# ReactJS - Passing data as props that I've just extracted from Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, parent-child, react-props

So i have just used the saveSavingGoalHandler to extract some Data from a child
component < SavingsGoal />..
i have it saved in SaveGoalData and when i run the Console.log() i get the correct
string.

The issue is i now need to pass it down to the other component < TransactionFeed />.
When i do savingGoalId={SaveGoalData} i get "SaveGoalData" is undefined..

my first thought was to us let SaveGoalData = "" outside the component then have
SaveGoalData = SavingsGoalID in the function but i just get undefined as it would
run the empty string before it gets filled..

any ideas???

```
    const saveSavingGoalHandler = (SavingsGoalID) => {
    let SaveGoalData = SavingsGoalID;
    console.log(SaveGoalData);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GetAccountName />
      <TransactionFeed
        accountUID={AccountID}
        defCategory={DefCategory}
        savingGoalId={SaveGoalData} <--- Is Undefined
      />
      <SavingsGoal
        accountUID={AccountID}
        defCategory={DefCategory}
        onSaveSavingGoal={saveSavingGoalHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Too little code to know what's wrong. I don't see where you declare `SaveGoalData`. You declare it in the functions, but where is the declaration outside of it?

Comment: We can't see your initial state, and you're not _setting_ state either. So I wouldn't be surprised that `SaveGoalData` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [saveGoalData, setSaveGoalData] = useState()
   const saveSavingGoalHandler = (SavingsGoalID) => {
    setSaveGoalData(SavingsGoalID)
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <GetAccountName />
      <TransactionFeed
        accountUID={AccountID}
        defCategory={DefCategory}
        savingGoalId={saveGoalData}
      />
      <SavingsGoal
        accountUID={AccountID}
        defCategory={DefCategory}
        onSaveSavingGoal={saveSavingGoalHandler}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you should be using `let SaveGoalData` outside of `saveSavingGoalHandler` since that let is available only in the scope of `saveSavingGoalHandler`.

I recommend using `setState({ SaveGoalData: SavingsGoalData })` inside `saveSavingGoalHandler` and reading the `SaveGoalData` from state in `TransactionFeed` props.

Side note: this seems like anti-pattern considering that data flow in React should be unidirectional.